# Using YouTube's PlayerAPI inside of a Google Chrome Extension under Manifest V2 -- works, but generating lots of warnings

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am receiving a couple of non-critical error messages when using YouTube's Player API inside of a Google Chrome Extension under v2.

I have the following definitions in my content_security_policy:

```
"content_security_policy": 
    "script-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com/player_api https://s.ytimg.com/yt/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vfl9Ni0ki.js; object-src 'self'"
```

The first reference, player_api, has a dependency on the widgetapi. This is clear if you navigate to the player_api url and look at its contents:

```
if (!window['YT']) {var YT = {};}if (!YT.Player) {(function(){var s = 'https:' + '//s.ytimg.com/yt/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflU5wlSl.js';var a = document.createElement('script');a.src = s;a.async = true;var b = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b);YT.embed_template = "\u003ciframe width=\"425\" height=\"344\" src=\"\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen\u003e\u003c\/iframe\u003e";})();}
```

That's all well and good. My content security policy works and YouTube videos load successfully. However, behind the scenes, I see a lot of warnings:

[image]

It is my understanding that the message "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL..." is unable to be removed or hidden. If anyone knows of a way to suppress this message, I would be very interested!

I do not have any understanding about the "Unable to post message to ..." error, though. A quick Google turns up a few people experiencing similiar issues, but I did not see any resolution. The widgetAPI is all minified -- making it hard to see what's actually going on.

Am I supposed to be receiving these errors? Is there a way to alleviate the errors? Or even suppress them (since they don't seem to actually break anything)?

Comment: The YouTube Frame API uses `postMessage` to interact with the frame. The errors are self-explanatory.

Comment: I don't find the error message self-explanatory at all. The error states, "Unable to post message." However, if I bring both files down as local copies and remove the offending line of code -- my player stops working. Re-adding the line of code causes it to work again, but the error message to show, too. The postMessage seems to be working as-intended... so why the error message?

Comment: Also, I only receive the message if I initialize on document.ready, if I initialize my player when my google chrome pop-up opens -- then it loads fine without any whining. Weird!

Comment: YAY! I figured it out. The issue was that I was calling the YT API on document ready, but what I really should've been doing was calling it on document load. This gives the iFrame the ability to fully load in place -- preventing these errors. :)

Comment: I am trying to do a similar thing using manifest version 2 and Youtube IFrame Player API. When I include https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflMypqMg/www-widgetapi.js in my Content Security Policy in manifest version, it still throws error of CSP violation for this file. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I also observed that the extension converts https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflMypqMg/www-widgetapi.js into https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflmypqmg/www-widgetapi.js. I don't know why it makes the whole URL lower case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unable to post message to http://www.youtube.com is resolved by wrapping the YTPlayer instantiation code with a $(window).load() instead of a $(document).ready.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of null is resolved by providing functions for onReady, onStateChange, and onError. You cannot provide null for one of these callbacks.

Comment: any idea how to fix this for Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the "Unsafe JavaScript attempt..." message is due to this bug in Chrome/Chromium:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17325

.. which prevents catching this exception while testing for direct cross-domain communication.

It's safe to ignore that message, but (until that bug gets fixed) there is no way to avoid those warnings.

The other questions have already been answered.