# youtube "Unable to post message to..." causing video analytics to not be tracked

Tags: youtube-api

We currently have a youtube video embedded on our homepage. Upon clicking play in the console we see the following message:

Unable to post message to http://www.youtube.com. Recipient has origin http://www.stitchlabs.com.

In the previous youtube google group it said that this error was harmless, and it appears it is in regards to playback, but we are noticing other issues with this. What I am noticing is that playbacks are not being recorded in the video analytics within our youtube account. This is specific to the video playback on our homepage and tourpages (www.stitchlabs.com). Playback from our video page or any of other channel partners embedded video pages is being logged. Any idea if these are related and if not what may be causing this?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if the two problems are related, but you can try to fix the first with this solution:

[Using YouTube's PlayerAPI inside of a Google Chrome Extension under Manifest V2 -- works, but generating lots of warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411290/using-youtubes-playerapi-inside-of-a-google-chrome-extension-under-manifest-v2)

> Unable to post message to http://www.youtube.com is resolved by
>   wrapping the YTPlayer instantiation code with a $(window).load()
>   instead of a $(document).ready.

and see if that solves the second problem

Answer (score 0):

The “Unable to post message to…” warning is not effecting your analytics.  This warning comes up when a call to postMessage is sent to a window that hasn't finished loading yet.  The player is trying to postMessage early to make sure the api is ready as soon as possible rather than waiting until the onLoad event which might fire well after the api is ready to use.

For the analytics portion, there are many things that could effect if a view is counted.  For example autoplay and scripted playbacks don't count towards your view count.  Here's a thread with details.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/ZZWcKmfFUvM