# YouTube iframe API official example gives errors

Tags: ajax, youtube, cross-browser, youtube-api

As of 2013-04-16 WEST, the [official getting started example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) of the YouTube iframe API results in error messages when run in Chrome 25 on WinXP/SP3:

[image: Chrome with error messages]

I am accessing the example [hosted](http://sites.inka.de/klee/youtube/getting_started.html) on a web server, i.e. not via the local file system.

Am I doing something wrong? Is the example / the API broken? Can you reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message has been around for quite a while -- as this Google Group post explains, it's due to an unresolved (4-year unresolved!) bug in WebKit:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/VKGl4ahBGyk

It shouldn't affect anything -- it certainly hasn't for our projects, and in visiting the demo URL you posted, it looks like it isn't affecting the API functionality there (i.e. in that demo, the video still stops after 6 seconds per what the code states). There was an SO question a while back that thought it might be affecting analytics:

[youtube "Unable to post message to..." causing video analytics to not be tracked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129902/youtube-unable-to-post-message-to-causing-video-analytics-to-not-be-tracked)

But it was never confirmed as being relevant.

It will be interesting to see if Chrome's move to the new Blink fork of WebKit leads to the bug itself being resolved.

Comment: Ah, it could even be that I was even aware about this when I developed a site more than a year ago (for internal use). I just was wondering why the site had stopped working, and so I looked at the error messages in the console. In the end it turned out that it's because I have Flash turned off by default in Chrome. On that site, the video iframe, and thus the puzzle piece image for missing plugin, is hidden until the video is loaded. Facepalm!